# how to detect SettingsFlyout is closed in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

Is there way to know when a settingsflyout is closed from the target page?

In SettingsFlyout, i can see BackClick event but this is only firing when user explicitly taps the back button in the SettingsFlyout. In order to dismiss the flyout, user can tap anywhere in the app page which will dismiss the flyout - at this stage, BackClick event is not firing.

My scenario is, based on settingsflyout option changes i need to reload my page contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unloaded event on the settingsflyout object